# Distribution of $r.(\ln(X)-X)$ when $X$ is beta distributed.

Tags: probability-distributions

I need some help and this is certainly not a home work question, as it appears in my research. 
If $X$ is a beta distributed random variable, is there a known distribution for 
\begin{equation} 
\begin{split}
Y & = r.(ln(X)-X)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

where $r$ is a constant? If not, is there at least an analytic form for the distribution of Y? 
I tried to derive one, but got stuck when I had to solve for $e^{y/r} = xe^{-x}$. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you dealing with the case where $X<0$, which is unavoidable since $X$ is normal?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the error! Sorry, in that case $Y = r(ln(-X)+X)$. I will change it.

Comment: Are you trying to solve $e^{y/r} = xe^{-x}$ for $x$? You can use the [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function $W$: if I didn't make a mistake, the solution to $\exp(cx)x=a$ is given by $x=W(ca)/c$, where $c=-1$ and $ a=e^{y/r} $.

Comment: I think this is super useful! Thank you so much. I think this will help in writing an analytic distribution for $Y$. You rock!

Answer (score 1):

From user3658307 insightful reply above, we have $x = -W(-e^{y/r})$, where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ function. Since the pdf of beta distribution is described by
$$f(x;\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} x^{\alpha-1}(1-x)^{\beta-1}$$ the pdf of $Y$ should technically follow:
$$f(y;\alpha,\beta) = \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} \left(-W(-e^{y/r})\right)^{\alpha-1}\left(1+W(-e^{y/r})\right)^{\beta-1}$$